# free node in linked list (C++)

Tags: c++

I wrote a code that supposed to be a stack (LIFO), and it work just fine except from the "pop" function that supposed to delete the last node in the linked list but instead it put some random values in it, If someone know how can I fix my code it will be great.
this is the struct:

```
typedef struct stack
{
    bool ActiveStructure;
    unsigned int element;
    struct stack* next;
} stack;
```

my main function:

```
#define PUSH 1
#define PULL 2
#define CLEAN 3
#define EXIT 4

int main()
{
    stack linkedStack;
    int maxSize = 0, newValue = 0, choice = 0, empty = 0;

    initStack(&linkedStack);

    do {
        std::cout << "1. push value into the stuck\n2. pop out value from the stuck\n3. clean stuck\n4. exit\nEnter your choice: ";
        std::cin >> choice;
        getchar();
        switch (choice)
        {
            case PUSH:

                std::cout << "Enter the value you want to add: ";
                std::cin >> newValue;
                getchar();

                push(&linkedStack, newValue);
                break;

            case PULL:
                empty = pop(&linkedStack);
                if (empty == -1)
                {
                    std::cout << "The stack is empty" << std::endl;
                }
                break;

            case CLEAN:
                if (!isEmpty(&linkedStack))
                {
                    cleanStack(&linkedStack);
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "the stack is empty" << std::endl;
                }
                break;

            case EXIT:
                std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl;
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != EXIT);
}
```

and this is the pop function

```
int pop(stack* s)
{
    if (!isEmpty(s))
    {
        stack* p = s;
        while (p->next)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        delete(p); /* this line do what she supposed to do when execited. but when I return to the main function suddenly the linkedStack->next has value in her and shes not NULL*/
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need to `typedef` your `struct`s in C++. Just do `struct stack { ... };`

Comment: You delete `p` but never set the pointer-to-`p` to NULL; hence the node before `p` is left pointing to an invalid (deleted) object.

Comment: I dont think I exactly understend what you mean. can you show it to me with code (in the pop function)

Comment: You have a problem in that `linkedStack` is an object so you can't have an empty list there is always one value in your list (the value of linkedStack).

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy Friesner already told you what is wrong. Here's your code:

```
int pop(stack* s)
{
    if (!isEmpty(s))
    {
        stack* p = s;
        while (p->next)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        delete(p);
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Imagine you have two items in your stack. For fun, let's call them `A` and `B`. `A->next` points to `B`. `B->next` points to `null`. So your code above is going to delete `B`.

But `A->next` still points to it. You've deleted it, so now `A->next` points to garbage.

You need to clean up that dangling pointer.

```
int pop(stack* s)
{
    if (!isEmpty(s))
    {
        stack* p = s;
        stack * last = nullptr;
        while (p->next)
        {
            last = p;
            p = p->next;
        }
        delete(p);
        if (last != nullptr) {
            last->next = nullptr;
        }
        else {
            // Not sure how you want to handle deleting the first element in the stack, as that's what you're passing in.
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch that you can't delete the first value.

Answer (score 0):

With this piece of code

```
 while (p->next)
 {
   p = p->next;
 }
```

you reach the last node of the linked list, then you do

```
 delete(p)
```

This does delete `p` for sure, but you never set its previous node to `null`, as you don't set it to null it points to an invalid memory location

What you can do instead is:

```
while (p->next) 
{
  prev = p;
  p = p->next;
}
delete(p);
prev->next = nullptr;
```

Comment: Careful. What's the initial value of `prev` and what happens if there is no `p->next`?